# Killing all processes generated by a form in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to build a list of all processes generated by events in a form and kill them all when the form closes.  How do I code this?

Comment: How are the processes generated?

Comment: When the form loads, an Excel workbook is loaded onto a webbrowser component.  I will like to kill that when the form closes.  I got it close when I press a exit button but for the life of me I can not seem to be able to use the same code for FormClose or FormClosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked with the Excel Interop we had several processes created by it, and we had problems if we had real Excel workbooks opened at the same time the program was running.

If you kill the process and your user has a workbook opened, you might close their Excel instead. I would suggest getting a list of the PIDs for the processes that have Excel in their name before opening the workbook in your program, then get the list again immediately after opening it, and by seeing what is new determine the PID of your process. When you're done with the workbook, kill the process with the PID you retrieved.

Edit: when you open the workbook in code, a new process is created. Before opening the workbook, you have a list of processes - let's say 10 (by usingpart of the code Harendra wrote). Then you open the workbook, and get the list again - and you'll have 11 processes (you might have more, but only one of those is Excel). By comparing the two lists, you get the ID of the new process, which is your opened workbook. You add to a list or processes opened by you, and when closing the program, kill all the processes from the list.

Comment: What if I open an Excel file outside the form.  Won't this give me a problem?

Comment: It would if you opened it right when you opened it in the application. Otherwise, it would opened outside of your check and it wouldn't be affected. You're not adding all excel processes to the list, only those that were opened after the workbook open call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i <= procList.Length - 1; i ++) {
    string strProcName = procList[i].ProcessName;

    string strProcTitle = procList[i].MainWindowTitle();
         //check for your process name.. here i m checking excel process
    if (strProcName.ToLower().Trim().Contains("excel")) {

        procList[i].Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: This one kills even those that I have opened outside the application.  I would like it to close only the ones that are generated by the form.

Comment: when your form generate process you can set some additional values like owner, discription etc to identify process.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation with reply from Harendra, you can store all the process ID of process invoked by you ! and close them at the time of closing.

This statement is valid only if you are using Process.Start to start processes

Comment: So, how do I go about generating the PID and killing the process with the said PID at the end?

Comment: @Rabin: If you call Process.Start you can assign the result of the start to a Process object, and get its ID:
Process newProcess = Process.Start(StartInfo);
MessageBox.Show(newProcess.Id.ToString());

To kill it, iterate through the list of processes, and when you find the one with this id, kill it.

Comment: But I am using Webbrowser component's Navigate to open the Excel workbook on the Webbrowser.

Comment: @Rabin : if you're not starting the process with Process.Start, I think the solution in my answer would work. Let me know if something is unclear so I can detail it.

Comment: I still don't get it.  Sorry.

Comment: I am sorry I think I did not phrase the question quite right.  What I want to do cycle through all Excel processes and kill the one generated by, say, "DataSheet.xls" plus any others generated by non active Excel files.

Comment: @Rabin: the process isn't generated by a file, and the file that was opened isn't visible in the process information, as far as I know. Also, how can you know which Excel files are inactive (and why)?
I've updated my answer with an explanation - it's not exactly what you're saying, but I think it does what you want to do.